# ActiveMerchant - Optimal method of sending money to user? PayPal account or Credit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have a website that will take payments from user A, hold them in our escrow account, then transfer the money minus a fee to user B.  I have the first part figured out, in terms of taking credit card payments from user A, but I'm trying to figure out the optimal method of taking that money and sending it to user B.  I'm not storing credit card info due to privacy and I don't mind requiring user B to sign up for a PayPal account if they're going to use the system but I don't know how to directly send payments to a PayPal account.

I'm using ActiveMerchant and the PayPal gateway on Rails 2.3.5.

I'm also open to any suggestions as to what the optimal method is to take money from user A, hold it for 1-60 days, then transfer it to user B while incurring minimal fees and something I can implement in Rails hopefully that won't cause me to have an aneurysm.

Comment: Most business plans that involve "take money from person A and give it to person B for a cut of the proceeds" turn out badly.  Required reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_mule

Comment: I appreciate the concern, thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1):

This may help You a bit
http://dimaspriyanto.com/2010/05/01/simple-paypal-transfer-using-active-merchant/

Comment: Too bad MassPayments are only available once you meet certain turnover. Which api can I use if I am just starting?

Comment: Link seems to be dead now.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a company that lets you capture funds for two months so you will need to get a merchant account and store the money in there until the time comes to send it to party B. You don't need anything special in terms of payment gateway. Authorize.net and a merchnat account could help you get the money and then you could distribute the money directly from their GUI if you don't want to get to technical. And later on you could automate sending the money if your crazy or have a backend that keeps track of your funds and distribution.